# UIViews not displayed properly after disabling size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

After trying a lot i am not able to figure out why my UIView is not being displayed same on different device. Initially i was using auto-layout and size classes but after having a lot of issues with it my senior told me to not use auto layout and disable size classes. So i did that but my view appears differently on 4s, 5s and 6s. This is how i placed all my elements in storyboard.

[image]

After i run the project on iPhone 4s it looks like.

[image]

On 5s (this is how it is supposed to look like on all devices):

[image]

On 6s (please ignore the screen dimmer effect):

[image]

Can someone please point out where am i going wrong. Thanks.
P.S: I was told to create a new project and start all over again, but the problem is i have already created some more view and there class file and i don't want to start all over again, also want to know what is causing this issue.

Comment: why are you disabling autolayout ? and why your senior gives this kind of advise? it is not a good solution that you facing some difficulties then stop to use this. your screen is too much easy to handle with autolayout. Now of you are not using autolayout then you can try auto resizing

Comment: @Lion - I have a lot more screens and want them all to appear the same on  all devices. I have to do what i have been told. And yes, i have auto resizing  enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Go on use size classes and then disable it while disabling it you will get an option

Keep size classes for, Select iPhone and you are ready to go.